# Expanding a collapsed section of a webpage automatically for webscraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a lot of links that I'm scraping for data. Here is one such link, `http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/c7375d5db21cbaae`

On that page, there are two collapsed sections that I need to extract data from; however, my code doesn't work on those parts. Is there a way to automatically expand the sections before my code starts scraping it?

Comment: Explore rselenium package that can control a browser to click and then retrieve content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This codes seems to read the tables correctly.

```
library(rvest)
page <- read_html("http://www.ufcstats.com/fight-details/c7375d5db21cbaae")
page %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
```

Can you clarify, what is not working for you?

Comment: I completely forgot about html_table() and went about it with a far more difficult method. thank you, this works perfect